# Creating a subscription/online calendar

Tags: r, calendar, icalendar

I am currently using R to create a calendar of events (using the calendar package) and creating an ical file, which I then save into outlook.  As these events can change from week to week and move around frequently I was wondering if there is a way to create a calendar which receives automatic updates to avoid having to manually generate a new calendar each week and delete the old calendar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

As far as I can tell the calendar package and ical package don't seem to have the necessary functionality.

Comment: Are you on windows?  Look at the RDCOMClient package and this thread for some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688915/rdcomclient-and-outlook-booking-a-meeting